# How to find the closest matching pair in two arrays to find result in last array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have three ArrayList's of doubles. One for latitude, longitude, and temperature. The arrays are all unsorted. The user has a cursor position on the globe, which should try finding the closest latitude and longitude pair in the table. The latitude and longitude pairs each correspond to a temperature in a table.

My problem is I can't think of a good way to iterate through these arrays to find the closest matching values.

What I've tried doing is iterating through the entire array and trying to find the closest values for longitude and latitude, but because they are unsorted it will always find the first value that is closest and stop. Another issue is that the values are in the decimal range, so the cursor position will never find an exact value in the table so I figure it has to be within +/- .00005 degrees.

If the cursor position did contain exact values corresponding to the table I imagine this would be a lot simpler, but there needs to be some sort of range that they can fall in (.00005), so I actually get returned a temperature result.

Example

```
    CLonArray = new ArrayList<>();
    CLatArray = new ArrayList<>();
    BolometricBrightnessArray = new ArrayList<>();

    double CenterLonCoord = Double.parseDouble(CenterLon);
    CLonArray.add(CenterLonCoord);

    double CenterLatCoord = Double.parseDouble(CenterLat);
    CLatArray.add(CenterLatCoord);

    double Tbol = Double.parseDouble(BolometricBrightness);
    BolometricBrightnessArray.add(Tbol);
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TDG3.png)

There's a lot of information online about finding the closest value to target in one array, but I need to find the closest value in two arrays and use those two values to find a match for temperature.

Any ideas on how to approach this would be appreciated! Not necessarily looking for most efficient way, but just a solution where I can check results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer was a comment: sort the arrays.

Then, writing it I think I've got what is your real problem: you have a point (selected by the User) and you need to find the closest point from a list. Hence, sorting is has no meaning. You can have the first value really close, but the other one really far away: more far than another point. This because the points are identified by a couple of values (latitude and longitude, but it's the same with x and y).

So, getting what is your problem, I think that the solution is to find for each couple of points the relative distance from each other. Getting the distance I think is a simple function, given that you know all the values: (userLat, userLon) and (pntLat, pntLon).

Once you have the list of values you can find the closest one really fast just scanning the list.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful, finding the relative distance between all points seems to be returning better results.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember also, as said in the other answer, that you've a sphere and the distance it's not as for planar surface. You need a formula that considers the couple lat, lon.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 bits of information I can give you that should help here

1. You should not be considering the lists of longitude and latitude as separate lists. They should instead be considered as a single list of points. Finding the point in your list that's closest to a user selected point is then as simple as checking how far each of the points in your list is from the user selected point, and taking the one which has the smallest distance.
2. Remember that longitude and latitude relate to points on a *sphere*, not a square. i.e. Which of these 2 points is closer to (-89.5, 0): (-89.5, 180), or (-88, 0). https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1359534351 gives the formula to convert from latitude and longitude to cartesian coordinates. (you're probably safe to assume that the radius of the earth is constant)